# How to split a string then convert into int in sql procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table with data and I want the convert it into an integer.

Example:

If the column has value:  example value

```
 ISNULL([Jan],0)+ISNULL([Feb],1) +ISNULL([Mar],3) +ISNULL([Apr],0) 
 +ISNULL([May],0) +ISNULL([Jun],0) +ISNULL([Jul],0) +ISNULL([Aug],1) 
 +ISNULL([Sep],0) +ISNULL([Oct],3) +ISNULL([Nov],0) +ISNULL([Dec],2)
```

I need the output as `10`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.  Your code seems to have nothing to do with converting a column to an integer.

Comment: Looks like you have a broken data model - if you have data of the same "type", such that it makes sense to compare values or, as here, add them together, that data ought to be stored in a *single* column (across more rows). It looks like you've designed your data storage based on a *form* or a *report* rather than thinking about the data structure itself.

Comment: ISNULL([Jan],0)+ISNULL([Feb],1) +ISNULL([Mar],3) +ISNULL([Apr],0) 
 +ISNULL([May],0) +ISNULL([Jun],0) +ISNULL([Jul],0) +ISNULL([Aug],1) 
 +ISNULL([Sep],0) +ISNULL([Oct],3) +ISNULL([Nov],0) +ISNULL([Dec],2)    this is the value in that column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added an extra column and row to demonstrate how to use several rows with different information.

This should do it:

```
DECLARE @t table(id int identity(1,1), a varchar(max))
INSERT @t values
('ISNULL([Jan],0)+ISNULL([Feb],1) +ISNULL([Mar],3) +ISNULL([Apr],0) 
 +ISNULL([May],0) +ISNULL([Jun],0) +ISNULL([Jul],0) +ISNULL([Aug],1) 
 +ISNULL([Sep],0) +ISNULL([Oct],3) +ISNULL([Nov],0) +ISNULL([Dec],2) '),

(' ISNULL([Jan],5)+ISNULL([Feb],1) +ISNULL([Mar],3) +ISNULL([Apr],0) 
 +ISNULL([May],0) +ISNULL([Jun],0) +ISNULL([Jul],0) +ISNULL([Aug],1) 
 +ISNULL([Sep],0) +ISNULL([Oct],3) +ISNULL([Nov],0) +ISNULL([Dec],2) ')

 SELECT id, sum(cast(t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)') as int)) x
 FROM (
     SELECT id, x = CAST('<t>' + 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(a, ',', '</t><t>'), ')', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
     FROM @t
 ) a
 CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c)
 WHERE isnumeric(t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)')) = 1
 GROUP BY id
```

Result:

```
id  x
1   10
2   15
```

Comment: That's a creative one! :)

Answer (score 0):

ISNULL isn't going to work as it will append the field if the field isn't NULL. As the others said, you should change the structure of your database preferably.

None the less... This should work if there is a row in the table.

```
Select [Jan] + [Feb] + [Mar] + [Apr] + [May] + [Jun] + [Jul] + [Aug] + [Sep] + [Oct] + [Nov] + [Dec]
From
(
Select
    CASE WHEN [Jan] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 0 END 'Jan',
    CASE WHEN [Feb] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'Feb',
    CASE WHEN [Mar] IS NULL THEN 3 ELSE 0 END 'Mar',
    CASE WHEN [Apr] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 0 END 'Apr',
    CASE WHEN [May] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 0 END 'May',
    CASE WHEN [Jun] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 0 END 'Jun',
    CASE WHEN [Jul] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 0 END 'Jul',
    CASE WHEN [Aug] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'Aug',
    CASE WHEN [Sep] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 0 END 'Sep',
    CASE WHEN [Oct] IS NULL THEN 3 ELSE 0 END 'Oct',
    CASE WHEN [Nov] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 0 END 'Nov',
    CASE WHEN [Dec] IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 0 END 'Dec'
From YourTable
) x
```

Comment: ISNULL([Jan],0)+ISNULL([Feb],1) +ISNULL([Mar],3) +ISNULL([Apr],0) 
 +ISNULL([May],0) +ISNULL([Jun],0) +ISNULL([Jul],0) +ISNULL([Aug],1) 
 +ISNULL([Sep],0) +ISNULL([Oct],3) +ISNULL([Nov],0) +ISNULL([Dec],2)     this is sample data only , some times it will be jan to feb , jan to march , or dec to mar, etc.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand what you mean there. If it's only certain month's you'd like to concentrate on at a particular time you just need to Add/Remove the CASE for that month.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
declare @cmd varchar(2000) = 'select ' + '

   ISNULL([Jan], 0) +ISNULL([Feb], 1) + ISNULL([Mar], 3) + ISNULL([Apr], 0)
 + ISNULL([May], 0) +ISNULL([Jun], 0) + ISNULL([Jul], 0) + ISNULL([Aug], 1)
 + ISNULL([Sep], 0) +ISNULL([Oct], 3) + ISNULL([Nov], 0) + ISNULL([Dec], 2)

' + ' from YourTableName';

execute (@cmd);
```

or:

```
declare @cmd varchar(2000) = 'select ' + (select ColumnName from YourTableName) + ' from YourTableName';

execute (@cmd);
```